# Delete an entry in hashmap while iterating

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration, remove-if

I have a loop to iterate a hashmap. If the condition is satisfied I need to remove the key, value pair from the hashmap. I am unable to do it using the below code. How can I achieve this?

```
for(HashMap.Entry<Integer,Character> m:commons.entrySet()){
    while(i!=(int)m.getKey()){
        i++;
    }
    if(s2.charAt(i)!=(int)m.getKey()){
      commons.remove((int)m.getKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show complete code please ? where does i variable come from ?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Character>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Character> entry = it.next();

    // casting to int is redundant in your code. I removed it.
    while (i != entry.getKey()) i++;

    if (s2.charAt(i) != entry.getKey()) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

You can use an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) to safely remove while iterating over a `Map`.

You can also look at [`.removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) (Java 8+), but with a loop inside your iteration, this is more readable, imo.

Comment: Thank you Harshal. It makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

1. The way you are trying to do it may cause `ConcurrentModificationException`. You should use an `Iterator` or [Collection::removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) which internally uses an `Iterator`.
2. Though you can compare a `char` with an `int`, probably you have mixed up key and value in the comparison. You have written

   ```
   if(s2.charAt(i)!=(int)m.getKey())
   ```

   in which you are comparing the `s2.charAt(i)` with the key which is an `Integer`. Syntactically, it is correct but probably you wanted to compare the value (which is a `Characater`) i.e. most likely you want to do

   ```
   if(s2.charAt(i)!=(int)m.getValue())
   ```

Do it as follows:

```
for (Iterator<Entry<Integer, Character>> itr = commons.entrySet().iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
    Entry<Integer, Character> entry = itr.next();

    while (i != entry.getKey()) {
        i++;
    }

    if (s2.charAt(i) != entry.getValue()) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Arvind. The concept is clearer for me now